# What prefix to use for custom builds with brew installed

Tags: c++, homebrew

I have a bunch of libraries which I maintain across Mac and Linux. I usually use prefix /usr/local for libraries. Though now I faced an issue on OS X with a library which was installed by brew and which other brew-installed libraries depend on.

IMHO /usr/local should be the "correct" path for *nix systems. Since that conflicts, and brings up complaints in brew, what alternative path should I use? /opt? Or rather /usr/local/opt (for each individual library)?

Comment: Which conflicts are you refering to?

Comment: What build system does your library use? Typically you expose a DESTDIR or PREFIX configuration variable to let package managers determine where your library goes.

Comment: Conflicting versions of Folly library. I need to maintain a same version among platforms for a reason.